# Programmatically Created Swipe Event

Tags: ios, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I would like to know how can I send a swipe gesture programmatically without actually swiping the phone. For instance, I have button that in the `onClick` event I would call `swipeGestureRecognizer`? Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the method you are calling on Swipe, when user taps on button. For examaple, you have a method for swipe gesture, call it `onSwipe` . Now call onSwipe methos when user taps on the button.  Thats it

**EDIT**

Here is the code for you:

```
-(void)myMethod{
 //Write the logic you want to implement for swipe gesture here.
}

-(IBAction)onClick(UIButton *)sender{
 [self myMethod];

}
-(IBAction)onSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
 [self myMethod];
}
```

There might be bugs on the code as I am just typing the code using windows. Correct it for yourself in MAC & edit the answer too. it would definitely work for you

Comment: if only it were that easy.... i tried that. set the buttons selector to the same method as the pangesturerecognizer but for some reason it just wont work that way.

Comment: No.. you don't have to do that.Just let me write code for you in my answer. I'll let you know when edit is done.

Comment: just calling method does not passes UISwipeGestureRecognizer gesture.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to pass the gesture event to the handler, then

```
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
    gesture.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    [self handleSwipe:gesture];
```